# phpspreadsheet How to pull formulas

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Is there a way to pull formulas? In my case pull down :)

Fill them all with 1 command is also fine.

Jan

Read the manual on https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but I found nothing usefull.

The question seems for me very clear but I must type 220 characters while less than 150 is already fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a look at the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get more clues about how to [post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).